# Nginx reverse proxy to a node express fullstack app not working

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js

I have a fullstack node express which serve static files and the api running on port 5000.

my nginx config is :

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mycoolserver.com;

        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       
       server_name fancyapp.mycoolserver.com;

       location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
       }
}
```

I can load the index.html at `http://fancyapp.mycoolserver.com` but the css and js from this file failed to be loaded.

If I try to access some of the api, eg: `http://fancyapp.mycoolserver.com/birds`, it's working.

I've read countless stackoverflow posts and google it for days without success.

Comment: You forgot the `root` directive.

Comment: it was intentional to omit root, because it's my node express which serves the static content. I just Nginx to proxy everything to my node app which serves the frontend and the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your site URL is not set correctly in your application.

I don't see any point to serve static assets via your backend application. You don't get practically any benefit from having nginx in the front...

Comment: I finally serve static assets from Nginx and use it as a reverse proxy only for the backend. Thanx for your answers.